# On which site do I ask questions about email scams?

Tags: discussion, spam, site-recommendation

Is there a Stack Overflow site for discussion on email scams and phishing?

Here's my question:

> I have dealt with a lot of spam over the years, as I am sure everyone else has. Gmail has gotten pretty good with their spam filters. But this is a recent occurrence, I can't quite figure out the point of it. Someone has gotten my gmail address and is creating accounts on online forums, like "Ranger Mods" is the most recent one. I get an email saying an account has been created on a web site using my email address. So, I verify it's an actual site, and follow the link and reset my password. Then I can log in and see what the profile shows. There's no name or other useful information there. So, what's the point? Are they just typing in the wrong email address? They have to know the owner of the email address is going to be notified, and will then log in and close the account? Is there some elaborate scam involved here? The emails that ask for your private information, I get how they work. Just trying to figure out why someone is using my email address. Most sites require a verification email before they let you in, don't they?

Comment: I absolutely would not be clicking the links in the email. Ever.

Answer (score 11):

You're asking a lot of questions there, so I'm not sure that would be warmly accepted on any site in the network. Some of your questions do appear to be rhetorical though ("So, what's the point?"), so you might be able to edit it into shape.

For example, if you just want to ask about what you can do to stop someone from using your email address in this way, it might be a good question for the [Information Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/) site. They already have tags for [`email`](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/email) and [`phishing`](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phishing), so if you look around you might find the answer already exists.